# How do I initialize a ForeignKey ModelChoiceField in Django?

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys, widget

This must be in the Django docs somewhere but I can't seem to find it.

Say I have the following models:

```
models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class MyOtherModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
```

And I create a form where I change the background color of the Select widget:

```
forms.py

class MyOtherModelForm(ModelForm):
    my_model=ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = MyOtherModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyOtherModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_model'].widget = Select(attrs={'style':'background_color:#F5F8EC'})
```

Everything works fine until the background color code is added.  As soon as I add that line, I get a colored but unpopulated select widget appearing.  I assume this is because once I specify some aspect of the widget's behavior, Django is looking for everything to be specified.

So how do I tell it to use the values from MyModel to populate the Select widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Overriding the default field types or widgets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets). Based on this I would try the following.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Select

class MyOtherModelForm(ModelForm):
    my_model=ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all(), widget=Select(attrs={'style':'background_color:#F5F8EC'}))

    class Meta:
        model = MyOtherModel
```

Also adding self.fields['my_model'].queryset = MyModel.objects.all() to your **init** might also work.

Comment: Thanks for the lead.  If I understand correctly, this indicates that I need to explicitly create a ModelChoiceField in the form.  I edited my code (and this question) to do that, but the Select widget remains empty.

Comment: The idea I have is that instead of overriding the __init__ method you could use the widgets = {} to add the required style to your select. I'm thinking that that might solve your issue with the empty select widget.

Comment: Looked a little further at that documentation and tried declaring the widget color under Meta.  When I do that I get an uncolored, populated dropdown.  If I leave the color specification where it is in the above question, I get a colored, unpopulated dropdown.

Comment: Yeah, that certainly seems to be what the docs say to do, but playing around further it seems that the behavior is completely controlled by the single line in __init__.  Adding or deleting the other lines as indicated by the documentation doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Hopefully that works. You could also apply the style outside of the model. Which is the route I normally take. I think the field id would be something like my_model_id so adding the following CSS to you template of and external CSS file should also work. #my_model_id{ your style }.

Comment: I was indicating that I'm still stuck; if I remove the line in init I haven't succeeded in what I was trying to do.  As for adding the style in the template, that is problematic because my implementation has a variable number of MyModels.  If I do it via styles externally I have to explicitly call out -id-01, -id-02, etc. which is kinda ugly.  So I'm still looking for the right answer here, but thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: My bad, when I said hopefully that works, I meant that I hope my last update worked. I make a adjustment to my answer. I added my_model=ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all(), widget=Select(attrs={'style':'background_color:#F5F8EC'}))

Comment: And I'm just not alert enough it seems ... yes!  That works.  Guess everything has to be initialized all at once.  Thanks very much for your help.